How to handle rpc request if server is overcrowded?
In our project, we are using brpc as our rpc framework. But brpc simply drops the request if the server is overcrowded(too many requests in queue). From the client side, we only know the request failed, so we want to return this error message. But we have concerns that this might add extra load to server as we will return extra message when the server is already overcrowded. Is there any already-exist production-level solution for this problem?
